# Methods to invoke remote scripts

Tags: javascript, web-applications

**Scenario**

A page invokes a remote script available at this url: `http://url.to.script/myScript?ScriptParamsList`. Let's assume that:

- Async execution is not required.
- Displaying output is not required.
- The script is called on a button click event. Let Handler() be the javascript event handler:

  `function Handler()
  {
    //invoke the remote script
  }`

Several methods are available to implement Handler() function:

- **script vs img tag**:

`document.write('<script src="http://url.to.script/myScript?ScriptParamsList" type="text/javascript"></script>');`

`document.write('<img src="http://url.to.script/myScript?ScriptParamsList" />');`

- **jQuery .html() vs .load()**:

`$('#TargetDiv').html('<img src="http://url.to.script/myScript?ScriptParamsList" />');`

`$('#TargetDiv').load('http://url.to.script/myScript?ScriptParamsList');`

**Question**

Which are the advantages and the disadvantages?

Comment: `<image>`? Do you mean `<img>`? You're comparing apples to oranges, by the way...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `document.write` will replace your current document when it's called after the document is loaded. Never use this method.
- Using `<script>` allows you to fetch a request from an external domain, without being hindered by the same origin policy. Additionally, in the server's response, you can add and execute JavaScript, which might be useful.
- Using `.html('<img ...>')` makes no sense, unless your server returns an image with meaningful data. If you intend to only trigger a server request, the following would be better:

  ```
  new Image().src = 'http://url.to.script/myScript?...';
  ```
- `$('..').load` is not going to work if the URL is located at a different domain, because of the [same origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript).

I vote for the `new Image().src = '..';` method. If you dislike this syntax, and want more jQuery, use:

```
$('<img>').attr('src', 'http://...');
```

Note: The result may be cached. If you don't want this to happen, append a random query string, to break the cache (eg. `url = url + '&_t=' + new Date().getTime()`).